# How to put MVC form in the center of the screen?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

The code in view looks as following:

```
@model StatusZN.Models.LoginViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Логин";
}

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 text-center">
        <section id="loginForm">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { autofocus = "autofocus", @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Логин" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>
                @Html.ActionLink("Зарегистрироваться", "Register") если у вас нет учетной записи.
            </p>
        }
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

The form is placed in top left corner. I've tried a lot of things, but it doesn't help. I'm using Bootstrap 3.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you tried?

You can use Bootstraps offset tool to push your form controls anywhere along the grid.

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 col-md-offset-2" })
```

This will push the label, and anything more right of the label, right 2 columns.
Always keep responsiveness in mind...

You must make sure your code is referencing the bootstrap css files in your cshtml.

Simply add this at the top of your .cshtml file. Reference below:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
<div class="row">
```

And when I run in debug this is the result. You can play with the grid system in bootstrap to get what you desire.

[image: image of centered bootstrap content]

Comment: I've tried to put main div to the center of the screen. I need to center whole block, not particular elements of the block. Can I do that using Bootstrap?

Comment: Your code haven't moved label to the center of the screen. Everything stays in top left corner of the screen.

Comment: For example I've tried "center-block" class, but it doesn't work. Actually, "center-block" does not contain in bootstrap.css. Where is "center-block"?

Comment: I use now bootstrap.css 3.0.1 where "center-block" exists, but it still doesn't work. I've tried a lot, a lot of things, but nothing is working.

Comment: You must add a reference to the css. Check updated answer.